# NSPredicate, get results with a subset of one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'mm working around with Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController`.

My Data Model looks like this:

`Product` with one-to-many relationship called `dataLines`. 
The `dataLine` entity has a property name `theWeek`.

I want to fetch all `Product` where `dataLines.theWeek == someValue`. This is easily done with a subquery. But this returns all dataLines. Is it possible to create a `NSPredicate` that returns the `Product` and a subset if dataLines only with the `dataLines == someValue`?

Comment: Please provide some code or add some details. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, could you explain what do you mean with *Is it possible to create a NSPredicate that returns the Product and a subset if dataLines only with the dataLines == someValue*? Is this the same goal of your first part question or not?

Answer (score 8):

What you want to achieve could be reached in two ways:

using a SUBQUERY

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(dataLines, $x, $x.theWeek == %@).@count > 0)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18]];
```

or the ANY modifier

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY dataLines.theWeek == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18]];
```

You can do also the following if you need to check against multiple values:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(dataLines, $x, $x.theWeek == %@ or $x.theWeek == %@).@count > 0)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18], [NSNumber numberWithInt:19]];
```

The same can be applied to `ANY` modifier. `ANY ... OR ANY ...`.

Maybe if you share some code we could help you.

P.S. I suppose you don't use scalar values and `theWeek` is a number.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the `dataLine` property instead.
Assuming your `Product` and `dataLine` entity connected by relationship `someRelation` then you can try this code;

```c
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityWithName:@"dataLine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataLines.week == %@",theWeek]];

NSMutableArray *tmpProduct [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (dataLine *theDataLine in tmpArray);
NSLog(@"%@",theDataLine.someRelation.name);
tmpProduct = theDataLine.someRelation.name;
```

then you can just call `tmpProduct` to call or display your product in table view

Answer (score 0):

Create a fetch request for the 'Product' entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" ...]]
```

then create a predicate using the properties/attributes of Product with 'ANY':

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY dataLines.theWeek == %@", <whatever week>]];
```

then execute the fetch to get an array of Product with at least one `<whatever week>`.

Generally see 'Fetching Managed Objects', NSPredicate and related documentation.

Comment: This is basicly what I am doing now. The problem is this returns all Products with all dataLines. What I want is:
Product A with dataLines.theWeek = 18 and dataLines.theWeek = 19. 
I want to return only Product A with dataLines.theWeek = 18. And not the dataLines.theWeek = 19. 
Is it possible?

Comment: It ia not clear–is this Product A the same object?If so, it is hard to understand your question

Comment: You want the fetched Product to have one and only one dataLine with, for example, the Week = 18?