# Search in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

In iOS in a Core Data project, I have an object graph where object `A` has a to-many relationship called fields. Every field is an instance of a class called `BlueField`. The class `BlueField` is a subclass of the class `Field`, which contains a string called header.

I want to retreive all instances of the class `A` that has a relationship to an instance of `BlueField` which has a certain value for the string header.

I have tried fetching objects with the following predicate with no sucess:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY fields.header CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];
```

Fetching with this predicate gives me no objects as response even though there are objects which should match the query. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Your predicate looks fine to me. Are you able to see elements in your store and verify if someone contains that text? You could use also a SUBQUERY. But I think the result will be the same. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857930/nspredicate-get-results-with-a-subset-of-one-to-many-relationship.

Comment: Thanks, the query seems to work fine if i search in non-subclassed objects, but not if i have instances of subclasses stored with a to-many relationship.